# Print input from user in WPF VB

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm working on project where the user will enter a JobNumber, say (J000001), and when the user hits print the jobnumber will print. With the code below, I'm able to print the numbers, say (001), but I want the user to enter the actual JobNumber (J000001). Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

When I enter the JobNumber (J000001), I get the following error message:

> 'Invalid CastException was unhandled'
>   Conversion from string "J000001" to type boolean is not valid.

Below is my VB Code:

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Drawing
Class MainWindow

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        AddHandler printDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf printDocument1_PrintPage
    End Sub

    'Declaration  the  global  variables 
    Private paperSize As New PaperSize("papersize", 300, 500)
    'set the paper size 
    Private totalnumber As Integer = 0
    'this is for total number of items of the list or array
    Private itemperpage As Integer = 0
    'this is for no of item per page 
    Private printDocument1 As New PrintDocument()
    Private printDialog1 As New System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog()
    Private DefaultFont As New Font("Calibri", 20)

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If txtStart.Text Then
            itemperpage = 1
            totalnumber = txtStart.Text
            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize
            printDialog1.ShowDialog()

            'printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "";
            printDocument1.Print()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid number")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function CheckNumber(str As String)
        Dim Num As Double
        Return Double.TryParse(str, Num)
    End Function

    'Define the  Printpage event of the printdocument 
    Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        Dim currentY As Single = 10
        While totalnumber <= CInt(txtStart.Text)
            ' check the number of items 
            e.Graphics.DrawString(totalnumber.ToString(), DefaultFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 50, currentY)


            'print each item
            currentY += 20
            ' set a gap between every item
            totalnumber += 1
            'increment count by 1
            If itemperpage < 1 Then
                ' check whether  the number of item(per page) is more than 1 or not
                itemperpage += 1
                ' increment itemperpage by 1
                ' set the HasMorePages property to false , so that no other page will not be added 
                e.HasMorePages = False
            Else

                ' if the number of item(per page) is more than 1 then add one page 
                itemperpage = 1
                'initiate itemperpage to 0 . 
                If totalnumber <= Convert.ToInt32(txtStart.Text) Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                End If
                'e.HasMorePages raised the PrintPage event once per page .           
                'It will call PrintPage event again
                Return
            End If
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="175" Width="303">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Start Number:" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtStart" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Print" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `If` statement in the `Button_Click` method.

```
If txtStart.Text Then
```

The `If` takes a boolean, but you are passing it a string.  VB.Net is trying to convert the string to a boolean.  001 works, because it can convert that.  J000001 is not able to be converted to a boolean.

Do you mean to check if there is a value entered?

```
If !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtStart.Text) Then
```

You will also run into a similar issue when assigning the value to `totalnumber`.

Comment: @a_hardin- For now I just want to print the user input. Can you give me hand on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the value of the text box as a boolean, and then assigning the value of your Text Box to a variable of type Integer.

```
If txtStart.Text Then
```

should probably be something like:

```
If !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStart.Text) Then
```

And then if you job numbers are alpha numeric, use a variable of type String instead of Integer.